# Google Analytics iOS SDK E-commerce transaction revenue is not showing up

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics iOS SDK (v3.0.7) in my app. I send successful order info at the end of the payment process. These are the line of codes that I send transaction to Google Analytics:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker;

tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createTransactionWithId:order.OrderNumber.stringValue
                                                     affiliation:@"iPhone"
                                                         revenue:checkout.TotalRevenue
                                                             tax:@0.0f
                                                        shipping:@0.0f
                                                    currencyCode:@"TRL"] build]];
```

Here's the `checkout.TotalRevenue` is an `NSNumber`. When i check GoogleAnalytics logs, I see this GET request:

```
(GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:509): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?av=1.5.2&cd=Menu&t=appview&ul=tr&_u=.oK-L&tid=XX-13174XXX-17&cid=XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX&sr=320x480&v=1&aid=mobile.app.something&_v=mi3.0.7&an=XXX&ht=XXX2905201XXX&qt=XXXXX&z=XXXXX
```

Also Google Analytics says status is 200;

```
Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
```

But when I check Google Analytics dashboard after 5-6 hours, I catch my transaction with the correct values except **Revenue** value. **Revenue** value always shows 0.00 TRL.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried changing currency code "TRL" to "TRY" for Turkish Liras.
[Google Analytics document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/currencies?hl=tr) says it should be "TRL", but it works with "TRY".